# A Lebesgue Integrable Function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

let $f \geq 0$ be a finite $a.e.$ on $E$ with finite measure. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and consider the following partition of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ for $n\geq 0$

$$0 = x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n < ...$$

with $\ \ \epsilon > \sup\limits_{n\geq 0}(x_{n+1} - x_{n}) $

Now define $E_n = \{x \in E: x_n \leq f(x) < x_{n+1} \}$ for $n\geq 0$

**Prove that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable $\iff \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n m(E_n)$ is finite and that**

$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0+}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n m(E_n)=\int_E \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$$

I can see why and understand it but I need help with the formulations and correct definitions.

So $f$ is a non-neg. Lebesgue integrable function, then its integral over $E$ is finite.

Since all $E_n$ are disjoint we have:

$$\int_E \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{E_0} \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{E_1} \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \ + ...= \int_{E_0} \! f(x) \, \mathrm{m(dx)} + \int_{E_1} \! f(x) \, \mathrm{m(dx)} \ + ... \\ \Longrightarrow \int_E \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x =\int_{E_0} \! f(x) \, x_0 + \int_{E_1} \! f(x) \, x_1 \ + ...$$

I don't know how to translate the integral of $f$ in each part of the partition $(x_n, x_{n+1})$ into the measure of the $E_n$'s

Comment: Hint: On each $E_n$ we have $x_{n+1}\geq f(x)\geq x_n$ and hence $ x_{n+1}m(E_n)\geq \int_{E_n}f(x)m(dx)\geq x_n m(E_n)$

Comment: @fKonrad then $x_0 m(E_0) + x_1 m(E_1)+... \leq \int_{E_0} \! f(x) \, \mathrm{m(dx)} + \int_{E_1} \! f(x) \, \mathrm{m(dx)} + ... \ \leq x_1 m(E_1) + x_2 m(E_2)...$ 
hence the inside Lebesgue integral equals both sides.

Comment: How does $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0+}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n m(E_n)$ affect $\int_E \! f(x) \, m(dx)$

Comment: Your $E_n$ are not disjoint. Replace $f(x)\le x_{n+1}$ by $f(x)<x_{n+1}$ in your definition of $E_n.$

Comment: C. Master $\int_{E_0} \! f(x) \, \mathrm{m(dx)} + \int_{E_1} \! f(x) \, \mathrm{m(dx)} + ... \ $ is not $\leq x_1 m(E_1) + x_2 m(E_2)...$ and the inside Lebesgue integral does not equal both sides.

Comment: The statement is not clear. Does the RHS of $\iff$ mean "is finite" for *some* $\epsilon$ *and some* $(x_n),$ or for all, or for a mixture?

Comment: @AnneBauval you were correct regarding $f(x) < x_{n+1}$. It is not less or equal. Why is that important?

Comment: Because if the $E_n$ are not disjoint, you don't have $\int f\,\mathrm dm=\sum\int_{E_n}f\,\mathrm dm.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum x_nm(E_n)\le\int f\,\mathrm dm\le\sum x_{n+1}m(E_n)\le\sum(x_n+\epsilon)m(E_n)\le\epsilon\cdot m(E)+\sum x_nm(E_n).$$